# is multiple states normal in a react-native app?

Tags: react-native

My app is running a split view screen with left and right sub screens, I am also using redux. I have one state for "SplitView", one state for "LeftScreen" and another for "RightScreen". These states control the navigation for each of them. It works well for the most parts except one thing which when I navigate, all three screen will be reloaded, and even the HTTP request will be reloaded each time I navigate either on "LeftScreen" or "RightScreen".

Is this normal? or is there a better way to handle state change/navigation?

thanks